# C++ adding 4 bytes to pointer address

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about pointers, and memory addresses:

Supposing I have the following code:

```
int * array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
```

Now in array im storing a memory address, I know that c++ takes already care when adding +1 to this pointer it will add 4 bytes, but what If I want to add manually 4 bytes?

```
array + 0x004
```

If im correct this will lead to add 4*4 (16) bytes, but my Idea is to add manually those 4 bytes.

Why? Just playing around, i've tried this and I got a totally different result from what I expected, then i've researched and i've seen that c++ takes already care when you add +1 to a pointer (it sums 4 bytes in this case).

Any idea?

Comment: something like `int* newpointer = (int*)(((char*)array) + 4);` could work

Comment: Is there a point  behind this question?

Comment: This is just math. `f(x) = array + 4 * x`. You want `f(x) = array + 4`. Solve for x.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It looks like you basically know how pointer arithmetic works.

Answer (score 1):

For a pointer `p` to a type `T` with value `v`, the expression `p+n` will (on most systems anyway) result in a pointer to the address `v+n*sizeof(T)`. To get a fixed-byte offset to the pointer, you can first cast it to a character pointer, like this:

```
reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + n)
```

In c++, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be equal to 1.

Do note that accessing improperly aligned values can have large performance penalties.

Another thing to note is that, in general, casting pointers to different types is not allowed (called the [strict aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) rule), but an exception is explicitly made for casting any pointer type to `char*` and back.

Comment: `accessing improperly aligned values can have large performance penalties. ` Or rather, behaviour of the program will be undefined as far as the C++ standard is concerned. Don't be surprised if the program misbehaves on ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if you add an arbitrary number of bytes to an address of an object of type `T`, it no longer makes sense to use a pointer of type `T`, since there might not be an object of type `T` at the incremented memory address.

If you want to access a particular byte of an object, you can do so using a pointer to a `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte`. Such objects are the size of a byte, so incrementing behaves just as you would like. Furthermore, while rules of C++ disallow accessing objects using incompatible pointers, these three types are excempt of that rule and are allowed to access objects of any type.

So, given

```
int * array = ....
```

You can access the byte at index 4 like this:

```
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(array);
auto byte_at_index_4 = ptr + 4;
```

---

> ```
> array + 0x004
> ```
>
> If im correct this will lead to add 4*4 (16) bytes

Assuming `sizeof(int)` happens to be 4, then yes. But size of int is not guaranteed to be 4.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is convert the type of `array` into any pointer-type with a size of 1 Byte, or store the pointer value in an integer.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int* increment_1(int* ptr) {
    //C-Style
    return (int*)(((char*)ptr) + 4);
}

int* increment_2(int* ptr) {
    //C++-Style
    char* result = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr);
    result += 4;
    return reinterpret_cast<int*>(result);
}

int* increment_3(int* ptr) {
    //Store in integer
    intptr_t result = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr);
    result += 4;
    return reinterpret_cast<int*>(result);
}
```